# spliting rows in crosstab jasper-report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, rows, crosstab

i'm working with jasper-report, i have this report i want to generate

[image: my report]

i have created a class in java, in which i have a field natureIntervention displayed on the columns, atelier on the rows and numero used for the count in the crosstab

```
public class ChampEtatMaintenanceParNatureIntervention {

    private String natureIntervention;
    private String atelier; 
    private String numero;


}
```

what i'm trying to display is for each row atelier, a list of vehicule types (ex: lourds, legers,....)

Comment: You need to give more info (some example of datasource, jrxml) can't understand from where the data will come relative to your different columns. Just put two field in the crosstab cell?

Comment: i want to display for each row atelier, a list of vehicule types (ex: lourds, legers,....), do i need to add a field List<TypeVehicule>? not necessarily two filds

Comment: that means for each TypeVehicule the number of natureIntervention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating crosstab with row and column groups on every record you need all information.

In your report is see

- 2 row groups (atelier and vehicule type)
- 1 column group (motor type)
- value of crosstab column

This suggest the following getters on your java object (that you pass as datasource)

```
public class MyDatasourceClass {    
    public String getAtelier(){.. return ...};
    public String getVehiculeType(){.. return ...};
    public String getMotorType(){.. return ...};
    public String getValue(){.. return ...}; //this maybe is another class
}
```

And your cross tab groups will be

```
<rowGroup name="atelier" width="150">
    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{atelier}]]></bucketExpression>
    </bucket>
    ... header value....
</rowGroup>

<rowGroup name="vehiculeType" width="150">
    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{vehiculeType}]]></bucketExpression>
    </bucket>
    ... header value....
</rowGroup>

<columnGroup name="motorType" width="150">
    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{motorType}]]></bucketExpression>
    </bucket>
    ... header value....
</columnGroup>
```